# The meaning of ‘there is’

Tags: meaning

I mean, it’s the very best school of witchcraft there is, I’ve heard.

In this sentence what’s the meaning of ‘there is’?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there_is. Please support our sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There is" means "that exists".

Answer (score 1):

*There*(usually used with *is/are*), in this context, is used to indicate the existing of something. For example:

> There are many restaurants around here.
>
> There's a very nice restaurant around the corner.
>
> In business, there comes a point when everything seems simple.